# jackson annotation to hide json type

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using spring boot and I use a composite key. I want to hide the type of the JSON object.I tried with the annotations like `@jsonIgnore`, `@jsonIgnoreType` and nothing works. I have this:

```
[ {
  "consumoId" : {
    "inc_acc_id" : "1069931929",
    "inc_clu_cellular_number" : "2954316800",
    "inc_description" : "Minutes"
  },
  "inc_frt_id" : null,
  "inc_unit" : "Min.",
  "inc_amount" : 0.0,
  "inc_quantity" : 22.68
}]
```

and I expect this:

```
[ {"inc_acc_id" : "1069931929",
    "inc_clu_cellular_number" : "2954316800",
    "inc_description" : "Minutes"  ,
    "inc_frt_id" : null,
    "inc_unit" : "Min.",
    "inc_amount" : 0.0,
    "inc_quantity" : 22.68
  }]
```

Comment: I don't think there is any annotations to accomplish this. You effectively want to move the properties of the composite key to the root node and remove the composite's node completely. See http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model and consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to inline the properties under the `consumoId` parent?

`@JsonIgnore` would skip it altogether, but `@JsonUnwrapped` will unwrap (omit) the containing object.